# Snakemake Cloud Execution & Large Files

Tags: snakemake

I've read the documentation (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cloud.html) and run the example project for the google life sciences executor. I am able to run my own workflows, but I'm having trouble running on large datasets.

It appears that snakemake is downloading to my local workstation the files generated by the jobs executed in the cloud. Some of these are much larger than disk space I have available, and I don't see a CLI flag to disable this, which makes me think there is a deeper conceptual issue.

In my mind, I would like my workstation to have light resource requirements and simply orchestrate execution in the cluster. I guess that since rules can conditionally execute based on inputs that I have to run snakemake from an environment that can locally store all of the intermediate results?

For context here's an example of the command I'm executing:

```bash
snakemake --google-lifesciences --google-lifesciences-region us-west1 --default-remote-prefix my-bucket --use-conda -j 3
```

It will populate a local directory `my-bucket/` with the output tree. So, if I have a step that blasts against NR, I need 500+GB of local storage which seems very resource inefficient if those files are only needed on job.

Comment: Not positive, but have you specified the files are remote? https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html

Comment: Granted I'm not familiar with cloud services, what you describe seems to defeat their purpose, at least in part. Do you observe that behavior also for the example pipelines or other well established pipelines? Can you post a reproducible example?